# heroku deployment error : undefined method `eager_load'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When I deploy my code to heroku I am getting an error. Here the full result. I don't know what I was missing. Here the trace of deployment.

```
    POST git-receive-pack (55210 bytes)
    remote: Compressing source files... done.[K
    remote: Building source:[K
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Ruby app detected[K
    remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails[K
    remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0[K
    remote: ###### WARNING:[K
    remote:        Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.[K
    remote:        Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.[K
    remote:        This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.[K
    remote:        In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.[K
    remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile[K
    remote: 
    remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.7.12[K
    remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4[K
    remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........[K
    remote:        Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..[K
    remote:        Resolving dependencies...[K
    remote:        Installing multi_json 1.10.1[K
    remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0[K
    remote:        Installing rake 10.4.2[K
    remote:        Installing builder 3.0.4[K
    remote:        Installing journey 1.0.4[K
    remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0[K
    remote:        Installing hike 1.2.3[K
    remote:        Installing rack 1.4.5[K
    remote:        Installing tilt 1.4.1[K
    remote:        Installing polyglot 0.3.5[K
    remote:        Installing mime-types 1.25.1[K
    remote:        Installing arel 3.0.3[K
    remote:        Installing acts_as_indexed 0.8.3[K
    remote:        Installing execjs 2.2.2[K
    remote:        Installing tzinfo 0.3.42[K
    remote:        Installing babosa 1.0.2[K
    remote:        Installing sass 3.4.10[K
    remote:        Using bundler 1.7.12[K
    remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.8.0[K
    remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1[K
    remote:        Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0[K
    remote:        Installing json 1.8.2[K
    remote:        Installing bcrypt 3.1.9[K
    remote:        Installing will_paginate 3.0.7[K
    remote:        Installing activesupport 3.2.15[K
    remote:        Installing rails-i18n 0.7.4[K
    remote:        Installing truncate_html 0.9.3[K
    remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3[K
    remote:        Installing rack-ssl 1.3.4[K
    remote:        Installing rack-cache 1.2[K
    remote:        Installing warden 1.2.3[K
    remote:        Installing dragonfly 0.9.15[K
    remote:        Installing sprockets 2.2.3[K
    remote:        Installing treetop 1.4.15[K
    remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.3.0[K
    remote:        Installing autoprefixer-rails 5.0.0.3[K
    remote:        Installing uglifier 2.7.0[K
    remote:        Installing bcrypt-ruby 3.1.5[K
    remote:        Installing activemodel 3.2.15[K
    remote:        Installing rdoc 3.12.2[K
    remote:        Installing mail 2.5.4[K
    remote:        Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.3[K
    remote:        Installing activerecord 3.2.15[K
    remote:        Installing actionpack 3.2.15[K
    remote:        Installing activeresource 3.2.15[K
    remote:        Installing friendly_id 4.0.10.1[K
    remote:        Installing awesome_nested_set 2.1.6[K
    remote:        Installing globalize 3.1.0[K
    remote:        Installing actionmailer 3.2.15[K
    remote:        Installing routing-filter 0.3.1[K
    remote:        Installing refinerycms-i18n 2.1.0[K
    remote:        Installing railties 3.2.15[K
    remote:        Installing decorators 1.0.4[K
    remote:        Installing coffee-rails 3.2.2[K
    remote:        Installing devise 2.2.8[K
    remote:        Installing jquery-rails 2.3.0[K
    remote:        Installing rails 3.2.15[K
    remote:        Installing seo_meta 1.4.0[K
    remote:        Installing sass-rails 3.2.6[K
    remote:        Installing refinerycms-core 2.1.5[K
    remote:        Installing refinerycms-dashboard 2.1.5[K
    remote:        Installing refinerycms-authentication 2.1.5[K
    remote:        Installing refinerycms-pages 2.1.5[K
    remote:        Installing refinerycms-images 2.1.5[K
    remote:        Installing refinerycms-resources 2.1.5[K
    remote:        Installing refinerycms-acts-as-indexed 1.0.0[K
    remote:        Installing refinerycms 2.1.5[K
    remote:        Installing pg 0.18.1[K
    remote:        Your bundle is complete![K
    remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.[K
    remote:        It was installed into ./vendor/bundle[K
    remote:        Post-install message from bcrypt-ruby:[K
    remote:        #######################################################[K
    remote:        The bcrypt-ruby gem has changed its name to just bcrypt.  Instead of[K
    remote:        installing `bcrypt-ruby`, you should install `bcrypt`.  Please update your[K
    remote:        dependencies accordingly.[K
    remote:        #######################################################[K
    remote:        Post-install message from rdoc:[K
    remote:        Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:[K
    remote:        <= 1.8.6 : unsupported[K
    remote:        = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install[K
    remote:        = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install[K
    remote:        >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay![K
    remote:        Post-install message from friendly_id:[K
    remote:        NOTE: FriendlyId 4.x breaks compatibility with 3.x. If you're upgrading[K
    remote:        from 3.x, please see this document:[K
    remote:        http://rubydoc.info/github/norman/friendly_id/master/file/WhatsNew.md[K
    remote:        Post-install message from globalize:[K
    remote:        Globalize has extracted versioning support to a separate gem named[K
    remote:        globalize-versioning. If you are using versioning (with paper_trail[K
    remote:        or any other versioning gem), please add the line[K
    remote:        "gem 'globalize-versioning'" to your Gemfile and go to the github[K
    remote:        page at globalize/globalize-versioning if you encounter any problems.[K
    remote:        Note that the globalize-versioning gem does not delegate versions to[K
    remote:        the translation table, so you will have to update your syntax to[K
    remote:        the form: `post.translation.versions`. See the globalize-versioning[K
    remote:        readme for details.[K
    remote:        Bundle completed (78.50s)[K
    remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.[K
    remote: -----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL[K
    remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline[K
    remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile[K
    remote:        DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/Rakefile:7)[K
    remote:        DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/Rakefile:7)[K
    remote:        rake aborted![K
    remote:        NoMethodError: undefined method `eager_load' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007fedb68f5448>[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/decorators-1.0.4/lib/decorators/railtie.rb:9:in `block in <class:Railtie>'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.15/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:69:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.15/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:95:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:23:in `invoke_or_reboot_rake_task'[K
    remote:        /tmp/build_b018b8090605ce25168bd072a38c1f66/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.15/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'[K
    remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary => assets:environment[K
    remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)[K
    remote:  ![K
    remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.[K
    remote:  ![K
    remote: [K
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app[K
    remote: 
    remote: Verifying deploy...[K
    remote: 
    remote: !   Push rejected to quiet-reaches-2872.[K
    remote: 
    Pushing to https://git.heroku.com/quiet-reaches-2872.git
    To https://git.heroku.com/quiet-reaches-2872.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/quiet-reaches-2872.git'
```

Comment: could you try `config.eager_load = false` in your production file

Comment: @pkrawat1 Yeah, That work find. But I am using `// =bootstrap-sprockets` in my app. So if I set `config.eager_load = false`, then error occurred on bootstrap-sprockets on application.js file.